# Microsoft CRM 2011 Online Fetchxml Report Error when loading into CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have created tons of reports in BIDS and deployed them to the online instance of my CRM. The issue I am having is with the following bit of code.

```
<fetch distinct="true" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
<entity name="quote" enableprefiltering="1"> 
<attribute name="quotenumber"/>
<attribute name="createdon"/>
<attribute name="ownerid"/>
<attribute name="description"/> 
<attribute name="quoteid"/> 
<link-entity name="quotedetail" alias="aa" to="quoteid" from="quoteid"> 
<attribute name="quantity"/>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Seems simple enough, but It is giving me the following error.

Invalid Data Source: The Report Type is not supported. Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online only supports reports that use FetchXML data Sources. PLEASE HELP. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect this to give you that error, but don't you need to specify the prefilterparametername when you specify enableprefiltering? Perhaps that is causing the FetchXML validation to fail?